# Blink a glyphicon

Tags: javascript, css, glyphicons

I am using glyphicon in kendogrid. I want the glyphicon to blink after a fixed interval of time.
My glyphicon is

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-one-fine-white-dot blink" title="{{ConsoleLabels.TTP_SENDING}}"></span>
```

Comment: why is happening, is your code broken, you have a error, you don't achieve the desired function?

Comment: i want to do it using javascript or jquery,i dont have any idea about this

Comment: you can do it with css animations

Answer (score 6):

Add this css in your page

```
.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {  
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
}
```

Note: For older version use prefixes

Comment: thank you for sharing this very simple but effective solution.

Comment: very nice and clean solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do it using javascript or jquery, here's a simple way to blink text (via `opacity`). The element will still keep it's proportions as a block but be hidden from view.

```js
var value = false;
setInterval(function(){  
  value = !value;
  $('[data-blink]').css('opacity', Number(value))
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<<span data-blink>Blinking Text</span>>
```